# MySqlworkbench is not connecting with warden. How I can fix this?

Tags: magento, mysql-workbench, warden

our connection attempt failed for user 'Magento' to the MySQL server at db:3306:
Cannot open SSH Tunnel: Failed to resolve hostname tunnel. warden.test (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

I ran the commands:

```
warden env down
//Then ran
warden env up
```

But it's not fixing my problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command and it fixed the error

```
warden svc up
```